# How to not give direct acess to folder but to it's inside documents

Tags: php, codeigniter

**environment**

```
       ---------codeigniter framework
       ----------document sharing, links to download the files
```

**mission**

```
--------------files are allowed to download
--------------the folder which contains the files are
              not allow to be seen by the user
```

Here I want to prohibit the user from seeing that folder, if I type the folder address I see all the files, I want to deny it. but the inside file not deny accessible

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `.htaccess` file in that folder. .htaccess files are used by the server to follow some set rules. You should create this file with a basic text editor such as notepad, but not MSWord or a wysiwyg editor.

Search your FTP, there might already be one, it might also be hidden so make sure you open the FTP with the option to see all files option `-a`.

In the retrieved or newly created file, put the line

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will disable folder listing, giving a "Forbidden" error.

Another option, is to simply put an `index.html` or `index.php` file in the folder, that way when typing the folder name as URL will serve the index page instead of the folder root. And it also allows you to display a user friendly error.

Personnaly, I use both options.